# Matrix: Gauss reduction

Tags: matlab, matrix

I'm trying to make a MATLAB function work that takes as input a matrix and returns the triangulated matrix. That's the function:

```
function T = gauss_method(A)

    [row, col] = size(A);

    T = zeros(size(A));

    for j = 1:col-1
        perno = A(j,j);

        for i = j+1:row
            mult = A(i,j) / perno;
            for x=i:col
                T(i,:) = A(i,:) - mult * A(j,:);
            end
        end
    end
```

Input is:

```
A = [3  1 -1   0;
     0  7 -3   0;
     0 -3  9  -2;
     0  0  4 -10];
```

Output is:

```
0         0         0         0
0    7.0000   -3.0000         0
0         0    7.7143   -2.0000
0    1.3333         0   -9.1111
```

Why doesn't it work? Where are the mistakes?

Comment: Hi Matteo - welcome on Stackoverflow! It is good to see that you tried hard, but there are a few things broken: your spacing; you never copy the first line to `T`; you may divide by 0 w.r.t. perno; since you update `T` but not `A`, you do not have the invariant Gauß requires... The easiest way to fix it would be to work inplace, so just use `A` for your implementation and change `mult = perno / A(i,j)` and only do the most nested body `if A(i,j) ~= 0` (with `A(i,:) = mult * A(i,:) - A(j,:)`). Hope this brings you in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your implementation is close to Gauss. However, there are some parts broken. Let's try to name them:

- Gauss is a recursive method in a sense that each step depends on the preceding ones. Therefore, assembling `T` from `A` without updating `A` cannot work. **Solution:** I suggest to work inplace, but you may also refer to `T` on the right side of your assembling-equation.
- You never touch the first line of `T` as you start with `j = 1` and `i = j + 1`. **Solution:**  One solution could be to copy the first line of `A` to `T` initially, or work inplace instead.
- You take the pivot element (`perno`) from the diagonal element. However, it is not said that all `A(i,i) ~= 0`. When dividing by `pernot`, you introduce a potential division by `0`. **Solution:**  You can avoid division at all, when implementing Gauss. Just scale the other line. In the end it is all about bringing `A` to triangle form by any form of linear combination.
- Talking about Gauss, I personally have the application of solving a linear equation system `A * x = b` in mind. **Suggestion:** Maybe you want to enable this by providing your function an optional argument `b` and transforming it along with `A`.
- The spacing is pretty broken, but this will hopefully be fixed with the outstanding edit of your question. **Suggestion:** Never use tabs for indents.

One proposal how to fix your implementation staying close to your current version:

```
function A = gauss_method(A)
    [row, col] = size(A);
    for j = 1:col-1
        perno = A(j,j);
        for i = j+1:row
            % alternative w/o division:
            %  A(i,:) = perno * A(i,:) - A(i,j) * A(j,:);

            % alternative w/ division:
            if A(i,j) ~= 0
                mult = perno / A(i,j);
                A(i,:) = mult * A(i,:) - A(j,:);
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Output:

```
>> gauss_method(A)

ans =

    3.0000    1.0000   -1.0000         0
         0    7.0000   -3.0000         0
         0         0  -18.0000    4.6667
         0         0         0   40.3333
```

Comment: Thanks for all your precious comment!